# If $A \subseteq B$, then $A_{\mathfrak p} \subseteq B_{\mathfrak q}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A \subseteq B$ be commutative rings with identity, $\mathfrak q$ a prime ideal of $B$, and $\mathfrak p = A \cap \mathfrak q$.  Is the 'identity' ring homomorphism $A_{\mathfrak p} \rightarrow B_{\mathfrak q}$ always an injection?  The 'obvious' method of proving this seems to lead to a dead end: if $\frac{a}{s} \in A_{\mathfrak p}$ is the zero element in $B_{\mathfrak q}$, then there exists a $t \in B$, but not in $\mathfrak q$, such that $ta = 0$.  But it isn't clear whether $t$ may be chosen to lie in $A$.  So my guess would be that this map doesn't need to be an injection.

The reason I'm asking is that it is an exercise in Hartshorne (II, 2.18) to show that a homomorphism of rings $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ is injective if and only if the corresponding morphism of sheaves $f^{\#}: \mathcal O_X \rightarrow f_{\ast} \mathcal O_Y$ is injective ($X$ and $Y$ are the spectra of $A, B$, and $f: Y \rightarrow X$ is the map $f(\mathfrak q) = \phi^{-1} \mathfrak q$).  Assuming $\phi$ is injective, I want to show that $f^{\#}$ is injective by showing the corresponding homomorphism on the stalks $A_{\phi^{-1}\mathfrak q} \rightarrow B_{\mathfrak q}$ is injective.  But if I am not mistaken, this homomorphism on the stalks is exactly the map $\frac{a}{s} \rightarrow \frac{\phi(a)}{\phi(s)}$ I just described.

EDIT: Someone has asked the same question before, and as I suspected the homomorphism $A_{\mathfrak p} \rightarrow B_{\mathfrak q}$ does not have to be an injection.  So my question now is **why this counterexample does not invalidate exercise II.2.18(b) in Hartshorne.**

EDIT 2: I just now realized the homomorphism on the stalks isn't the natural map $A_{\phi^{-1}\mathfrak q} \rightarrow B_{\mathfrak q}$; the codomain isn't correct.  Rather, if $\mathfrak p = \phi^{-1}\mathfrak q$, $(f_{\ast} \mathcal O_Y)_{\mathfrak p}$ is the direct limit of the rings $\mathcal O_{Spec B}(f^{-1}U)$, where $U$ runs through the open neighborhoods of $\mathfrak p$.

Comment: I think this question should be closed, the difficulty I had with this problem now turns out to be something else entirely.

Comment: I've reopened, since it's no longer a duplicate. Now you should think about whether you'd prefer to delete the question, supposing others won't have the same question, or to flesh out your second edit to an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close my question as off-topic because it should be asked as a totally new question.  After I got something cleared up, the title and most of the question now don't match what I want to know.

Comment: You don't need to have one question closed in order to ask another one. Since T.S.L. answered a part of the question, I suggest truncating the question only to the part about II.2.18b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for Hartshorne II.2.18b,

Let $p \in X$ and consider the stalk map $f_p^\# : \mathcal{O}_{X,p} \to (f_* \mathcal{O}_Y)_p$. By definition of the direct image functor and using that $\mathcal{O}_{X,p} = A_p$ and a similar result for $B$ shows that this is equivalent to considering $A_p \to B_p$ where we are thinking of $B$ as an $A$-module via $A \to B$. Since $A \to B$ is injective and injection is local, we are done.